# Trigger.io and KendoUI Mobile - Layout / view doesn show up until touch

Tags: android, android-webview, kendo-ui, trigger.io

I am trying to work with trigger.io and Kendoui Mobile.
the point is, when launching the mobile app on emulator all works like expected - but when it runs on android mobile the Layout / View doesnt show up until you touch the screen or turn the mobile to landscape or viceversa.

with a tabstrip of kendoui one time showed up you can swtich between views with no problems.
but if you redirect to another view with different layout you have to touch again the screen to show the content (it just shows just the background of body until touch).

the telerik guys at the moment dont know from where it comes from as they tested it with phonegap and no problems.

Maybe the trigger.io guys can find out why it happens?

Best regards
marc

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem with an Android hybrid app based on Trigger.io (testing device: Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.4). It all seems like the renderer needs a kick (like touch or orientation change) in order to process the latest DOM changes.

Comment: I tried with .hide() and .show() by jquery in data-show event with no luck. tried it over document, body, id selector of view and layout, e.view and e.layout.

Comment: On the device I was talking about (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) the problem seems to be fixed after upgrading to Android 4.1.1 Jelly Bean. I was also not able to reproduce it on the simulator (tried both Android 4.0.3 and 4.1).

Comment: Yeah but it is not a solution to the problem :/ - we cant force customers to use a specific minor version on the mobile just to work with app. Will try to get in touch with the trigger.io guys.

Comment: Of course! Is it possible that you are using [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for custom scrolling? Also, I was experiencing the issue on the Android 4.0.4 Emulator, so it's not specific to Galaxy Nexus devices.

Comment: No not using iScroll, just a layout with  tabstrip in header, and hello world text in view is enough to get the issue.

Comment: OK, James from Trigger here: we're looking at this and have narrowed it down a bit. We've only been able to reproduce on 4.0.x, and find the issue only surfaces if you clear the RAM or re-install the app. Feels like a timing issue at the moment, but will update when we know more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is an issue with hardware acceleration on Android 4.0, probably an unfortunate interaction between whatever hardware accelerated transitions Kendo UI use and that particular version of Android.

Phonegap seem to have hardware acceleration disabled by default, which is why they would not be affected.

As a fix we are going to add an option to disable hardware acceleration on that particular Android version, which we'll have live by the end of the week.

Comment: Fix is live: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-12. You'll need to use "disable_ics_acceleration" in your app config: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/requirements.html#android